# Convert number into word function python

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to write 2 functions in python. One of the functions should be able to take one parameter and convert a number from 1 to 10 into words. E.g. if 2 is the input from the user it should return two. The second function should take 2 parameters and list out the values from the user input. E.g. if the 2 values input from the user is 2 and 8 it should print 2-8 in a new line. However, I want to convert the numbers into words. E.g. it is should print two-eight all in a new line. This is what I have written so far.

```
def numberToText(z):                                                    
  if(z==1):                                                 
    return "one"                                                    
  elif(z==2):                                                   
    return "two"                                                    
  elif(z==3):                                                   
    return "three"                                                  
  elif(z==4):                                                   
    return "four"                                                   
  elif(z==5):                                                   
    return "five"                                                   
  elif(z==6):                                                   
    return "six"                                                    
  elif(z==7):                                                   
    return "seven"                                                  
  elif(z==8):                                                   
    return "eight"                                                  
  elif(z==9):                                                   
    return "nine"                                                   
  elif(z==10):                                                  
    return "ten"                                                    
                                                    
                                                    
def count(x,y):                                                 
  for x in range(x,y+1):                                                    
    print(x)                                                    
    numberToText(x)                                                 
                                                    
x=input("Enter first number")                                                   
y=input("Enter second number")                                                  
count(x,y)
```

I think i have got the call to the first function incorrect but I'm not sure. Please help?

Comment: Maybe you want `print(numberToText(x))`?

Comment: You should print return of `numberToText(x)`, now you print `x`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add quotation (or backticks) around the entities that are strings (for example 'two' instead of two). And add an example of the input and the output you want for your functions.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step 1 is to _read the error message_. What does it say? `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`, in line `for x in range(x,y+1):` What's `x`? A _string_. What's `y`? Another _string_. You can't add a number `1` to a string. You need to first convert your inputs to integers. Also note that `for x in range(x,y+1):` redefines `x`. You won't be able to use the original input `x` after this.

Comment: Thanks i have fixed the problem.

Comment: it would be a lot better and more readable to put all the strings into a list `['one', ...'ten']` and then index it `lst[z-1]`

Answer (score 4):

Cast the input into integer

```
x=int(input("Enter first number"))                                                 
y=int(input("Enter second number"))
```

Comment: Thanks I have now found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you input your number, the input function returns a string. For example if you input "1" the value of x is the string "1" and not the integer 1. Therefore, you need to cast the input to an integer since that is what you are expecting.

```py
x = int(input("Enter first number"))
y = int(input("Enter second number"))
count(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remember that you can use some useful functions which will give you more details about currently used data etc. In your case it can be problem with a type returned by function input()

```
input() # This function returns string
count() # As I can see from code it requires int's

# You can check current variable type with function 
type()
# if you want to print result just check something like this
x=input("Enter first number")
print(type(x))

# then try:
x=int(input("Enter first number"))
print(type(x))
```